# How to create a JsonObject of complex structure like given below in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
{
    "A": {
        "B": {
            "C": {
                "D": "123"
            },
            "E": {
                "F": {
                    "G": "aaabbb"
                },
                "H": "QWE",
                "I": {
                    "J": "003",
                    "K": "01"
                }
            },
            "L": {
                "M": {
                    "N": "1603",
                    "O": "QWE"
                },
                "P": "N",
                "Q": "N"
            },
            "R": {
                "S": "10000",
                "T": "QWE"
            },
            "U": {
                "V": "0",
                "W": "13"
            },
            "X": {
                "Y": "123456"
            }
        },
        "ABC": {
            "QQ": "5",
            "WW": "O"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a similar Json String without having to create all these classes A, B, C, etc. I could create it by creating classes for each of these tags A, B, C, etc using ObjectMapper of Jackson Library. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use nested maps or directly build the hierarchy using Jackson's `TreeNode` and implementations.

Comment: Could you get me a rough example exactly how this can be achieved?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in my comment, there are a couple of ways.

**Nested Maps**

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    
map.computeIfAbsent("A", k -> new HashMap<>())
   .computeIfAbsent("B", k -> new HashMap<>())
   .computeIfAbsent("C", k -> new HashMap<>())
   .put("D", "123");
        
((Map<String, String>)map.computeIfAbsent("A", k -> new HashMap<>())
     .computeIfAbsent("B", k -> new HashMap<>())
     .computeIfAbsent("E", k -> new HashMap<>())
     .computeIfAbsent("F", k -> new HashMap<String, String>()))
     .put("G", "aaabbb");       
    
String json = om.writeValueAsString(map);
```

Methods like `computeIfAbsent()` help a lot in in having to check for the presence of intermediate maps all the time but as you can see, if the structure is not uniform this can get awkward to handle.

Of course you can build the maps in other ways, this is just a simple demonstration.

**Using ObjecNode (and ArrayNode if required)**

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode root = om.createObjectNode();
ObjectNode nodeA = om.createObjectNode();
root.set("A", nodeA);
    
ObjectNode nodeB = om.createObjectNode();
nodeA.set("B", nodeB);
    
ObjectNode nodeC = om.createObjectNode();
nodeB.set("C", nodeC);
nodeC.put("D", "123");
    
ObjectNode nodeE = om.createObjectNode();
nodeB.set("E", nodeE);
    
ObjectNode nodeF = om.createObjectNode();
nodeE.set("F", nodeF);
nodeF.put("G", "aaabbb");

String json = om.writeValueAsString(root);
```

Again there are multiple ways to construct this node hierarchy.

Both examples produce the following (unformatted) json which reflects the first portion of your structure:

```
{"A":{"B":{"C":{"D":"123"},"E":{"F":{"G":"aaabbb"}}}}}
```

Comment: Your code was very helpful @thomas! I would like to get some insights on how you manage to code it so efficiently. Honestly, if not for you, I would have created 10 different classes and made the JSON String after building root class's object.

Comment: @AakashThakur thanks, I'd say this is just experience (with Jackson and coding in general) and a desire to write readable yet efficient code :) I'm pretty sure there are a lot of areas where my code would be a lot worse :)

Comment: Imagine the same structure JSON is what I receive as response. Could you tell me a similar approach to read those values? @Thomas

Comment: @AakashThakur you could use the `readTree()` method to get a `JsonNode` which you'd need to check for being an `ObjectNode` instance. Or you could use `readValue()` and pass a `TypeReference<Map<String, ?>>` or so. `readTree()` is probably easier.

Comment: So I would first create nodes in which I am expecting the response and then parse String type Response which is in Json format to Json node? I am not sure I understood.

Comment: @AakashThakur no, you use `readTree()`, get back the root node and then need to traverse the tree and look for the data you want or look what data it contains.